# Get name of file from filechooser

Tags: c, gtk, filechooser

I am trying to get the name of a file when I select it using a file chooser.

I managed to do

```
    gchar *name = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(open_dialog);
```

but that will return `/home/user/Desktop/test.file` and not `test.file` which I want to.

Is there any method to get the name of the file and not the uri of it?

Comment: Why don't you just extract the filename from that path?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you open the file if you have no the whole "URI" (path) to it?? If you want only `test.file` you can extract it from the whole path. There's the POSIX function [basename](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/basename/) and glib has a function too: [g_path_get_basename](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-path-get-basename).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using GIO (http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/). Its GFile and GFileInfo structures can be used for exactly what you need (also, GIO has the advantage to provide you with a portable file handling API).